# How to minimize $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2$ subject to $ \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, extreme-value-analysis

Let $x,y$ be positive real numbers satisfying $xy \le \frac{1}{4}$.

I am trying to find
$$ \min_{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{2}}(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2$$

as a function of $x$ and $y$.

Is there any way to do that analytically?

**Edit:**

Is there a way to use a computer for this? I tried running Mathematica, but it never finishes the computation...

Lagrange’s multipliers method gives

$$
(a-x)=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt a}\\ (b-y)=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt b}.
$$

In particular,
$$ (a-x)=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\cdot(y-b).$$

I tried various ways to proceed but got stuck.

Comment: @PeterSzilas: the unknowns are $a,b$ and $x,y$ are given; they break the symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $a:=2(\frac12+t)^2,b:=2(\frac12-t)^2$ we minimize

$$(x-2(\tfrac12+t)^2)^2+(y-2(\tfrac12-t)^2)^2.$$

By differentiating on $t$ we get (after simplification)

$$8t^3+2(3-x-y)t+y-x=0.$$

This is a general (depressed) cubic equation, and there is no hope for a nice solution.

---

Note that $\sqrt a+\sqrt b=1$ describes an arc of parabola (the axis is the first bissector), and you are looking for the shortest distance between the point $(x,y)$ and this arc.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if anything more can still be said about this cubic equation, e.g. how many real roots does it have? Wolframe alpha suggests that there is only one real root, but I am not sure.

Comment: @AsafShachar: when $x=y$, a solution is $t=0$ and there can be two other real ones of arbitrary value.

Answer (score -1):

So we want to minimize $\left(\frac1{ a}+\frac1{ b}\right)\lambda^2$.
If $ab\le \frac14$, we can of course take $\lambda=0$, i.e., $x=a$, $y=b$ and achieve the minimum value $0$.
So assume $ab>\frac14$.
From
$$ \frac14\ge xy=\left(a-\frac\lambda{\sqrt a}\right)\left(b-\frac\lambda{\sqrt b}\right)=ab-\left(\sqrt{\frac ab}+\sqrt{\frac ba}\right)\lambda+\frac{\lambda^2}{\sqrt{ab}},$$
we read off that we shold take the smaller of the two (necessarily positive) roots of the quadratic
$$ X^2-\left(a+b\right)X+\left(ab-\frac14\right)\sqrt {ab},$$
i.e.,
$$\lambda=\frac{a+b-\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab-4ab\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ab}}}2=\frac{a+b-\sqrt{(a-b)^2+(2\sqrt {ab}-\sqrt[4]{ab})^2}}2 $$

Comment: I  think that there is a problem with your answer. $x,y$ are given in advance, you can't choose them to be $x=a,y=b$ unless they satisfy $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{2}$. Also, since $a,b$ satisfy $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{2}$, we know that $ab \le \frac{1}{4}$, by the AM-GM inequality, so the second option that you mentioned $ab > \frac{1}{4}$ cannot occur.